# C# Retrieve Stored Procedures from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

Good Afternoon,

We are currently working on a tool, which retrieves all the `Stored Procedures` in a given database, which then extracts each `Table` being used in each Stored Procedure.

Currently, I got all of the `Stored Procedures` in a `List`, don't know if there are any parsers available that I can pass the `Stored Procedure` and returns the `Tables` being used.

The plan is then to link each `Stored Procedure` with the `Tables` being used in a Graph Database.

Thanks

Comment: You have to show some code or mock output of your list so people can actually help you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no prewrited methods to get that. You have to request the database tables, then check in each stored procedure query if it contains the table name.

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

This query will return the tables in the database